# What type of Christianity does Hans Christian Andersen depict in *The Red Shoes*?

Tags: denomination-survey, culture, christian-literature

When I was little, my parents used to read to me a Chinese version of the story, *The Red Shoes*, by Hans Christian Andersen. Though, I was not aware of the story's Christian themes and motifs until I read the English version, a language that I am more fluent in.

There are some defining characteristics:

- the girl cannot wear red, presumably because it's a sinful color (?)
- the girl must wear black shoes to church
- the girl cannot wear red during her mother's funeral; it's socially forbidden
- the red shoes are very distracting to the girl, perhaps the epitome of sin
- the girl must ***literally*** repent and forsake her "sinful" life, marked by the red shoes
- the type of Christian that Andersen depicts cannot show pride when other people admire her dress or her looks; she must be modest or humble, and that means ignoring the good things about her

What type of Christianity is this, or is this just a figment of Hans Christian Andersen's imagination, or is it a generic nameless type of Christianity as in Margaret Atwood's *The Handmaid's Tale*?

Comment: I believe there were Jesuits in The Handmaid's Tale, whatever the Generic Christianity was, it was not Jesuitical! (to me, this makes it slightly less generic)

Comment: Yeah, plus the fact that Catholics were discriminated against in the story.

Comment: @PeterTurner I meant to refer to The Handmaid's Tale in my previous comment.

Answer (score 3):

In western culture, Red is the color of passion and it's disordered vice of lust is cooped up in the color. (see also, the Scarlet letter). I see the esteemed Revered V says the sin is pride.  I don't disagree, I just think the real sin that is being covered here is lust and not pride.  Karen has a disordered desire to dance and be seen when she should stand still and keep quiet.

As far as the particular religion is concerned.  I don't see it being Catholicism:

> She went to the *parsonage*, and begged that she might be taken into service there.

Parsonage is a is a Protestant term, now, either he's just using the wrong word there, which is understandable or he's referring to someone else,  if it were Catholic, we'd call it a Rectory, not a parsonage. I don't think he didn't wrote deliberately Catholic stories like the Grimm brothers did, but I'm not an expert and have read more Grimm's Fairy Tales than his.

---

So, my answer would be, the same type of Christianity that Nathanael Hawthorne portrays in The Scarlet Letter, good old fashioned puritanism.